# R- making a vector out of a list of classes

Tags: r

Let's say I define a class of some sort, That has fields `name` and `grade` for example. Now let's say I define a list of instances of this class.

How can I extract from this list a vector containing only the grades (with the same order they were in the list)?

Is there a fast way to do it without using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to say whether this will work without some sample code from you, but this might do the trick.

```
getGrade <- function(myObj){myObj$grade}
gradeList <- lapply(objList, getGrade)
gradeVec <- unlist(gradeList)
```

Or, collapsing that into a one liner.

```
gradeVec <- unlist(lapply(objList, function(x)x$grade))
```

Comment: Just to be picky - `lapply` is in fact a `for` loop as well: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/776708efe6003e36f02587ad47b2eaaaa19e2f69/doc/manual/R-exts.c#L175-L190

Comment: thanks a lot. So does that mean that this solution is not more efficient than the ordinary for loop I've made?